Issues with synchronization with multiprocessing.Lock
I am initializing multiprocessing.Lock() in a worker process. like:
with multiprocessing.Lock(): shared_value+=1 
is it any different passing a single instance from the parent process through all worker processes?
Does it cause sync issues. Cause I can see shared_value becoming ambiguous values.
I tried passing a single instance of Lock() through all the workers and it doesnt cause it.
Also do I require to create a Pool since I am creating each process, starting each in a loop and store it in a list. And I use the list to calll process.join() each in a loop in the end. What does creating a Pool do here?

Multiprocessing Manager gives you two options. Firstly a Lock and secondly a Value
Let's say we want to run N processes where each process adds 1 to a managed Value then:
import multiprocessing as mp

N = 10

def process(value, lock):
    with lock:
        value.value += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        lock = manager.Lock()
        value = manager.Value(int, 0)
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            pool.starmap(process, [(value, lock) for _ in range(N)])
        assert value.value == N
        print(value.value)

